# Unable to add account in Google Hangouts

Tags: iphone, google-apps

I've been unable to login to Google Hangouts via the iPhone mobile app. I keep getting "Unable to add account". I've tried restarting my phone, nothing changes. If it helps, I am using a legacy business account from Google.

iPhone: 5s
OS: iOS 7.1.2
App: Hangouts from Google Inc, 2.1.0

[image]

Comment: Are you able to log into Hangouts using that account in a web browser?

Comment: Yes, I am able to log into Hangouts using any web browser on my computer.

Comment: If you are using a Google Apps account, do you know if Hangouts is enabled for your account? Your admin needs to enable Hangouts, but I'm assuming they've already done that if you can log into Hangouts using a web browser. https://support.google.com/a/answer/4213662

Comment: I definitely do have access to the Google Hangouts.
http://i.imgur.com/hYr6TOi.png

Answer (score 1):

If the account you're trying to login with us managed with Family Link, then you cannot access Hangouts on an iPad or iPhone. See https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/2944865

I also tried Google Duo, but that silent fails to login and just boots you back to the login screen.

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable Google+ in your Google App account to let your phone use Hangout. Login to Google App admin, then choose "More controls" at the bottom and choose "Other Google Services". Then you can see Google+ in the list.